# Conky Widget stuck on Desktop

Tags: conky

Used

sudo apt-get --purge remove package conky

sudo apt-get remove conky-all

But the widget is still showing on the homescreen.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting?

Comment: I just booted my system and now it's gone. Thanks Robby1212!!

Comment: I felt kind of silly asking but good to know!